# C++ Basic While Loop: Unknown Inputs and Value Increment

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to write a program that reads unknown inputs from a data file that has a sentinel 0 or I guess an termination point for the loop.

- Number of integers per line before 0 (int count).
- Number of all integers in data file (int totalcount).
- Number of lines in data file (int lines).

Two examples of unknown inputs from a data file:

- Example One:
  1 2 3 0 4 5 6 7 0
- Example Two:
  0 9 11 -11
  1 1 0 0 2
  0

Here is my program (without "count" because that is where my problem lies):

```
int main()
{
    //Declaring variables.
    int input, lines, count, totalcount, datafile;
    lines = 0;
    count = 0;
    totalcount = 0;

    //Loop runs as long as data file has an integer to take in.
    while(cin >> datafile)
        {
            //If datafile is not 0, loop runs until datafile is 0.  
            while(datafile != 0)
                {
                    //Counts all integers in the file except 0.
                    totalcount += 1; 
                    cin >> datafile;
                }
            //Counts how many lines there are in a data file using sentinel 0 (not "/n").
            if(datafile == 0)
                lines += 1;  
            //Outputs.
            cout << lines << setw(11) << count << setw(11) << totalcount << endl;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Please do not worry about technicality, efficiency, or anything else besides the logic/concept itself as I'm just trying to find the missing link in my knowledge to complete this assignment.

With that said, my expected outputs are as formatted:
"Line #"      "Counts of integers per line"      "Total counts of all integers in data file"

Using example **one** with my current code, I would have outputs (spacing is not exact and '.' is for blanks):

> 1......0......3
>   2......0......7

Correct expected outputs:

> 1......3......3
>   2......4......7

I would like any hints or explanation of how I can count the integers per line (before sentinel 0) and assign that value to "int count" without the value persisting to the next line.

I'm a student in an introductory C++ class so please show me a basic way of how I may go about this first and then any other advanced options as necessary for future applications.

Code of Conduct Personal Statement:
By participating, you are providing necessary knowledge for assignment completion, not completing the assignment itself. The example used is generated by me intended for concept demonstration purposes and is only a small part of the final assignment.

10/23/2016 9:56PM Update 1:
Currently attempting to use a "temp" variable to substract from "totalcount". I will update my code if attempt is successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

totalcount is sum of counts. This is my suggestion

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Declaring variables.
    int input, lines, count, totalcount, datafile;
    lines = 0;
    count = 0;
    totalcount = 0;

    //Loop runs as long as data file has an integer to take in.
    while(cin >> datafile)
        {
            // Add count to totalcount and reset count each time reach 0
            if (datafile == 0) {
                totalcount += count;
                lines += 1;  

                cout << lines << setw(11) << count << setw(11) << totalcount << endl;
                count = 0;
            } 
            //otherwise increase count
            else {
                count++;
            }

        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I knew I made this out to be too complicated than it needs to be. The assignment as a whole implements loops heavily so I failed to recognize the use of basic selection statements. Thank you for putting a stop to my overthinking!

Comment: I test ran my program just now and it does in fact give the >totalcount as desired for my specific program assignment. My professor gives an example data file with its expected output values and everything looks fine.

Comment: I'm sure I'm the least experienced but if I'm not mistaken, count will increment until cin gets a 0, which will reset count to 0. But before count is assigned a 0, the value in count has already been added to totalcount. Wouldn't this mean that totalcount will have an increment of 1 for every integer except 0 and count will have an increment of 1 for every integer between intervals (0,0)? Using example set {1 2 3 0 4 5 6 7 0}.

Comment: @Abhineet Yes I made a mistake. You are right for seeing that because I was looking at my assignment as a whole and it asks for the total output only once which is why it stayed the same in my example.

Comment: @Abhineet I wrote the same totalcount with the intention in mind at the time of showing the difference between count and totalcount. I will edit this post for future browsers. Thanks for pointing that out and thanks to Khoi for giving me the intended correct answer with my mistake.

Comment: "http://ideone.com/pB8HTV" vs "http://ideone.com/xSuy5k" See the difference for yourself.

Comment: I see the mistake I made in the post which led to the misunderstand here. To finalize everything, in my program, the totalcount is the number of all integers in the file, this is correct. But also, it is only suppose to display once at the end which makes it fine for the method Khoi demonstrated. The reason why I had totalcount displayed per line is just to show the difference between count and totalcount. Also, I did not want to give out too much of my assignment for integrity reasons. So to sum it all up, Khoi unintentionally solved my problem as I intended.

Comment: @Abhineet While you have correctly pointed out my mistake that would otherwise lead to a different program which means this method would not work correctly as we will not have the final sum of all integers in the file before outputting totalcount per line.

Comment: @Abhineet There are no hurt feelings. The lengthy comments we have here are just to clarify that Khoi answered my **intended** question correctly, though unintentionally. While you pointed out an error in my original post that led to many confusion and I appreciate that. I have edited my example to be consistent with my question so that others who stumble upon this post won't leave more puzzled. Please don't take it as if I was upset.

Comment: @SamSafary your question description makes me confused for a while when the sample output didn't match the 2nd requirement ("Number of all integers in data file (int totalcount)", 0 is surely an integer, sample out just count non-zeros). 
After reading 1st requirement, I guess 0 is consider as an "end-line" over the "the break". That's all end up is my lucky code :) 
If these requirement is the original from your professor/teacher, please ask him/her for more details. If the anything is redefined (in this example 0 mean "end-line", not integer), it should be descripted clearly.

Comment: @khôinguyễn Yea I figured that can be confusing that's why my opening statement says, "So I'm trying to write a program that reads unknown inputs from a data file that has a sentinel 0 or I guess a termination point for the loop." Also in my code itself, i wrote: "//Counts how many lines there are in a data file using sentinel 0 (not "/n")." So I thought I was clear that "0" is my end-line condition, but this is my first post so hopefully next time I can do a better job at writing a question :/